# Using PdfLaTeX Via Overleaf: Error When \maketitle

Tags: pdftex

This is a **solved** problem with the template from ELSEVIER when using Overleaf, which can be downloaded at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/els-cas-templates/. Then occur six errors after adding:

```
\maketitle
```

Errors:

[image]
[image]

And a minimal example is shown below, u may use Overleaf to check.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb} % Add
\usepackage{bbding} % Add
\usepackage{color} % Add

%%%Author macros
\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\tsc{WGM}
\tsc{QE}
%%%

\begin{document}

\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}

\shorttitle{US}    
\shortauthors{Z}  
\title [mode = title]{US}  

% -------------------------------- Authors -------------------------------- %

\author[a]{Z}[style=chinese]

% Corresponding author indication
\cormark[<corr mark no>]

% Footnote of the first author
\fnmark[<footnote mark no>]

% Email id of the first author
\ead{A}

% URL of the first author
% \ead[url]{<URL>}

% Credit authorship
\credit{A}

% Address/affiliation
\affiliation[a]{organization={A},
            addressline={A}, 
            % city={},
            % citysep={}, % Uncomment if no comma needed between city and postcode
            postcode={A}, 
            % state={},
            country={A}}

\author[a]{A}[style=chinese]

% Footnote of the second author
\fnmark[*]

% Email id of the second author
\ead{A}

% Credit authorship
\credit{A}

% Corresponding author text
\cortext[1]{Corresponding author}

% -------------------------------- Abstract -------------------------------- %

\begin{abstract}
A
\end{abstract}

% -------------------------------- Keywords -------------------------------- %

\begin{keywords}
\sep A
\end{keywords}

% -------------------------------- Introduction -------------------------------- %

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{1}

A

% -------------------------------- Biography -------------------------------- %

\end{document}
```

Thanks to everyone in advance! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must fill in something for the placeholders in

```
\cormark[<corr mark no>]
```

and

```
\fnmark[<footnote mark no>]
```

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb} % Add
\usepackage{bbding} % Add
\usepackage{color} % Add

%%%Author macros
\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\tsc{WGM}
\tsc{QE}
%%%

\begin{document}

\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}

\shorttitle{US}    
\shortauthors{Z}  
\title [mode = title]{US}  

% -------------------------------- Authors -------------------------------- %

\author[a]{Z}[style=chinese]

% Corresponding author indication
\cormark[1]

% Footnote of the first author
\fnmark[1]

% Email id of the first author
\ead{A}

% URL of the first author
% \ead[url]{<URL>}

% Credit authorship
\credit{A}

% Address/affiliation
\affiliation[a]{organization={A},
            addressline={A}, 
            % city={},
            % citysep={}, % Uncomment if no comma needed between city and postcode
            postcode={A}, 
            % state={},
            country={A}}

\author[a]{A}[style=chinese]

% Footnote of the second author
\fnmark[*]

% Email id of the second author
\ead{A}

% Credit authorship
\credit{A}

% Corresponding author text
\cortext[1]{Corresponding author}

% -------------------------------- Abstract -------------------------------- %

\begin{abstract}
A
\end{abstract}

% -------------------------------- Keywords -------------------------------- %

\begin{keywords}
\sep A
\end{keywords}

% -------------------------------- Introduction -------------------------------- %

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{1}

A

% -------------------------------- Biography -------------------------------- %

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ohhh, Thx! I got it, may I ask one more thing? Cause I still get a warning: Package hyperref Warning: Ignoring empty anchor on input line 162. What may cause this warning?

Comment: @Tim That's en error of the class you use. It loads the hyperref package at the wrong place.

Comment: Got it, Thx! This should be fixed by their chairman, I will continue on my own work :D

Comment: @Tim .. or you could ask the package maintainers to fix this, the contact info can be found in the documentation https://www.ctan.org/pkg/els-cas-templates/

Comment: Yeah, it's a good suggestion :)